# c++ - abstract class and alternative to virtual constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, abstract-class

Let say I have the following code:

```
class Block{
private:
  data Data;
public:
  data getData();
  Block(arg3 Arg3, arg4 Arg4);
};
```

Actually, there are several ways to build a block, but always with the same member Data and method getData(), the only difference is how to build the block. In other words, the only difference is the constructor...

Instead of writing a different class for each building process, I could factorize parts of my code, defining and declaring getData in an abstract class, if there were such thing as a virtual constructor in c++ that I could write differently for each derived class corresponding to a different building process.

I do not have a lot experience for this kind of things, so I wondered if there was an alternative to a virtual constructor ? or may be a different way to do this factorization ?

PS: I am aware of https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-ctors but it seems quite complex regarding what I want to do, which seems quite common... I just want to factorize shared code between several classes, which corresponds to everything except the constructor. And I want to force new classes corresponding to other building processes to implement a new constructor.

**More details about my particular situation:**

I have an algorithm where I use blocks and it does not depend on their building process, so I have implemented the algorithm using a template argument to represent a block indifferently of its building process. But I use a few methods and its constructor, so I need my classes representing blocks to all have the same kind of methods I need and the same constructor to use them as a template argument of my algorithm implementation. That is why I thought of abstract class, to force a newly implemented class representing blocks to have the methods and the constructor I need in the algorithm I implemented. May be it is a bad design pattern and that is why I am stuck...

**EDIT**

Thank you for your answers so far. I tried to be a little generic but I feel that it is actually too vague, even with the details I gave at the end. So here is what I thought to do: I have a Matrix class as follows

```
// Matrix.hpp
template<typename GenericBlock> class Matrix{
  std::vector<GenericBlock> blocks;
  Matrix(arg1 Arg1, arg2 Arg2);
};

template<typename GenericBlock>
Matrix<GenericBlock>::Matrix(arg1 Arg1, arg2 Arg2){
  // Do stuff
  GenericBlock B(arg3 Arg3, arg4 Arg4);
  B.getData();
}
```

The blocks are actually compressed, and there exists several ways to compress them and it does not change anything in the class `Matrix`. To avoid writing a matrix class for each compression technics, I used a template argument as you saw. So I just need to write a class for each compression technics, but they must have the same methods and constructor arguments to be compatible with `Matrix`.

That is why I thought of doing an abstract class, for writing a class for each compression technics. In the abstract class, I would write everything needed in `Matrix` so that every derived class would be compatible with `Matrix`. My problem now in my example is: I can define `getData` in the abstract class because it is always the same (for example, `Data`can be the number of rows). The only thing derived classes would really need to define is the constructor.

One solution would be to not have an abstract class and use a protected constructor may be. But it does not force newly derived class to reimplement a constructor. That is why I am stuck. But I think this problem is generic enough to interest other people. So is there an alternative to a virtual constructor in this case ? (may be a factory pattern but it seems quite complex for a such common problem) If not, is there a better way to implement a matrix class whose blocks can be built in different manners, i.e. whose constructor can be different from each other, while having the same data and a few method in common ?

PS: I am interested in compression technics that produce low rank matrices, that is why the data is always the same, but not the building process.

Comment: Why not just have multiple constructors? Seems to me you are over-complicating things.

Comment: If you want to configure block building strategy at runtime - why don't use abstract factory?

Comment: @JesperJuhl what do you mean ?

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can understand your problems better.

Comment: See "named constructor" idiom

Comment: Imho this a an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is hard to understand what you actually need. Can you show an example of what you want to do / what you would like to do and why it doesnt work?

Comment: Regarding your EDIT, what actually goes wrong when you try what you suggested? It works fine for me, no need for a virtual constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have shared so far it is not clear why you need an abstract class or virtual constructors. A factory function for each way of building a block will do:

```
class Block {
  Data data;
public:
  Block(Data d) : data(std::move(d)) {}
  Data getData();
};

Block createABlock() { return Block{Data{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}}; }  
Block createBBlock() { return Block{Data{42.0, 3.14, 11.6}}; }

int main() {
  auto b1 = createABlock();
  auto b2 = createBBlock();
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R4nn53nqV26KZKTl).

Perhaps this needs to be extended with an abstract factory so you can pass a generic block factory around:

```
using BlockFactory = std::function<Block()>;

int main() {   
  BlockFactory f = createABlock;
  auto b3 = f();   
}
```

**EDIT**:
Regarding your EDIT, what you have suggested [works fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KIEtj1fheKPZk7GO). You don't need a virtual constructor. The template type `GenericBlock` just has to satisfy the implicit interface defined by the template. It doesn't need to derive from a particular base class (although it could do). The only thing required of it, is it must have a constructor that takes a particular set of arguments and a `getData` method. What you have is compile time static polymorphism, virtual functions are for run time dynamic polymorphism.

Inheritance will work fine but as I said above I'd be tempted to use some sort of factory. You may not need to template the whole `Matrix` class as only the constructor needs the factory. If the factory is known at compile-time this can be passed as a template parameter:

```
class Matrix {
  std::vector<Block> blocks;
 public:

  template<typename BlockFactory>
  Matrix(BlockFactory f);
};

template<typename BlockFactory>
Matrix::Matrix(BlockFactory f){

  // Do stuff...

  Block B = f();
  auto data = B.getData();
  for (auto v : data)
    std::cout << v << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
  Matrix ma(createABlock);
  Matrix mb(createBBlock);
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bD8ff6efG4N46IeZ).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to force newly derived class to define a constructor the way it was needed in the `Matrix` class, that is why I thought of a "virtual constructor" (which does not exist). But as you said, `GenericBlock` has to satisfy the implicit interface anyway, I guess I was over-complicating things. I ended up doing what you suggested in your EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR, but if the `data` are the same for all `Block`s, you don't even need multiple classes, but only multiple constructors.

```
class Block
{
  enum { type1, type2, type3 };
  int type;
  data Data;
public:
  Block(int x)
  : type(type1), Data(x) {}
  Block(std::string const& str)
  : type(type2), Data(str) {}
  Block(data const*x)
  : type(type3), Data(data) {}
  /* ... */
};
```

Comment: I need the constructor to have the same arguments, actually, all the building processes take the same arguments.

Comment: As I said at the end of my question, I want to use these blocks as template arguments of an algorithm I implemented, such that they need to have the same list of arguments for the constructor.

Comment: @PierreMarchand only now I read your edit and latest comments. tbh I dont understand at all. How can your algorithm not depend on how the blocks are build when it calls the constructor and this call should be the same for all types of blocks... at what point gets decided what type of block is supposed to be created?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{constexpr tag_t(){}; usong type=T;};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
```

this lets you pass types as values.

```
struct BlockA{};
struct BlockB{};

class Block {
  enum BlockType { typeA, typeB };;
  BlockType type;
  data Data;
public:
  Block(tag_t<BlockA>, int x)
  : type(typeA), Data(x) {}
  Block(tag_t<BlockB>, int x)
  : type(typeB), Data(2*x+7) {}
/* ... */
};
```

the blocks are all the same type.  The tag determines how they are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative to a virtual constructor, because there is no virtual constructor to begin with. I know it can be hard to accept, but it is the truth.

Anyhow, you do not need anything like what a virtual constructor would be if it existed....

> [..] the only difference is how to build the block. In other words, the
>   only difference is the constructor...

If the only difference is in the constructor, then simply make the constructor take a parameter that tells what type of block is required. Alternatively you can have some functions that construct blocks in different ways:

```
struct Block {
    private:
        Block(){}
        friend Block createWoodenBlock();
        friend Block createStoneBlock();
};

Block createWoodenBlock(){ return Block(); }
Block createStoneBlock(){ return Block(); }


int main() {
    Block woody = createWoodenBlock();
    Block stony = createStoneBlock();
}
```